# Uploading a audio file to s3 with django-audiofield, django-storages, boto. django-storages This backend doesn't support absolute paths error

Tags: python, django, audio, amazon-s3, boto

```
Django==1.8
django-audiofield==0.6.4
boto==2.38.0
django-storages==1.1.8
```

I am currently having issue uploading an audio file to S3. All the images are being uploaded correctly. When I try to upload the audio I get:
Exception Type: NotImplementedError
Exception Value: This backend doesn't support absolute paths.
Exception Location: .../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py in path, line 115.

Heres the end of the trace back...

```
.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/audiofield/fields.py in _set_audio_converted
                    filename = self.generate_filename(instance, os.path.basename(getattr(instance, self.name).path)) ...


.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py in _get_path
                    return self.storage.path(self.name) ...


...c/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py in path
                    raise NotImplementedError("This backend doesn't support absolute paths.") ...
```

I think its too do with

> path(name)[source]¶
>   The local filesystem path where the file can be opened using Python’s standard open(). For storage systems that aren’t accessible from the local filesystem, this will raise NotImplementedError instead.

from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/files/storage/

Comment: I have got it working... not perfect but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working... not perfect but it works. I needed to rewrite part of the django-audiofield fields.py. Specifically the `def _rename_audio` and `def _set_audio_converted` as they both included the path method which doesn't work if you are not serving your static files from local.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I received this error because I had an extra Save method.

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    # def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    #     img = Image.open(self.image.path)

    #     if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
    #         output_size = (300, 300)
    #         img.thumbnail(output_size)
    #         img.save(self.image.path)`
```

The error message went away after I disabled the image resizing and save method.